# How to return value from an extended casperjs function?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to return a value from the below function like so.

```
html = casper.get_HTML(myselector);
```

All I am getting returned is "undefined" (return_html).  However, the 'html' variable is getting set properly.  The over all function works properly. It's just the return value that is the issue.

How do you do it?

```
casper.get_HTML = function(myselector) {
    var return_html;

    casper.waitForSelector(myselector,
        function() {
            var html = casper.getHTML(myselector, false);
            return_html = html;                                     //got the html
        },
        function() {                                                // Do this on timeout
            return_html = null;
        },
       10000                                                       // wait 10 secs
    );

    return return_html;
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CasperJS all `then*` and all `wait*` functions are step functions which are asynchronous. It means that you cannot return something that is determined asynchronously in your custom function. You have to use a callback:

```
casper.get_HTML = function(myselector, callback) {
    this.waitForSelector(myselector,
        function then() {
            var html = this.getHTML(myselector, false);
            callback(html);
        },
        function onTimeout() {
            callback();
        },
        10000 // wait 10 secs
    );
    return this; // return this so that you can chain the calls
};

casper.start(url).get_HTML("#myid", function(html){
    if (html) {
        this.echo("success");
    } else {
        this.echo("failed");
    }
}).run();
```